# Framework 7 Tabs - Get Tabs Count and the active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

i would like to get the number of tabs and the current active tab in framework 7 tabs component. I want to put an indicator that shows the number of tabs and a highlight to the active tab. Like carousel slider indicator 
Can i access is with its dom or using jquery. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a particular class to the tabs (or use the tab class), then use the jQuery property [**length**](https://api.jquery.com/length/) to determine the number of elements with a given class.

For example

```
$(".tab").length
```

will give you the number of instances with the class **tab**, hence the number of tabs.

For the active tab, again you can use some jQuery to select the ID (if that's what you are interested in) of the tab with the **active** class

```
$('.tab-active').attr('id')
```

Comment: hi yes im aware you can do that. but i believe thats improper. framework 7 already had that i believe, but its not in t he docs.

Comment: Why do you believe its improper? If there was an "official" way to do it, like you said, it would be in the docs. One of the strengths of Framework7 is that is borrows a lot from jQuery which means you can use jQuery to get things done, and not have to learn something new .

Comment: yes, but the answer you said will be my last resort if there not in the docs. anyway thanks